# Using Mod Rewrite with DJango redirecting to Port Number

Tags: django, apache, mod-rewrite, mod-wsgi

I have Mod rewrite set to pick up people who come to the root of my domain and redirect them to the proper language folder in my Django

Im running a new Django with mod_wsgi under apache.   I have an apache instance  with a virtual server set to port 8005 and my load balancer pointed to that server and port.

I have only one rule in Mod Rewrite to redirect to US folder

```
    RewriteRule ^(|/|/index.html)$ /us/ [QSA,NE,R=302,L]
```

When I try to go to my www.site.com I see in my trace logs its trying to redirect to www.site.com:8005/us/  instead it should go to www.site.com/us/

If I go to  www.site.com/us/  works fine

Answer (score 0):

In the apache configs i needed add servername hostname   I had a different hostname that was preventing it from redirecting properly.  I haven esperienced this problem on my non Django sites